# MS Word creating hell with footnotes

Tags: footnote

I've written a long academic document in Mac Pages that has had to be converted to MS Word for proofreading and typesetting purposes. I have installed the latest version of MS Word for my Macbook M1 and converted the Pages document to Word, but for some reason the footnotes and references are refusing to abide by the same formatting rules as the rest of the document.

1. Firstly, WORD ignores all find and replace queries for references in the footnotes. I am having to fix them one at a time, but even then it behaves as if it were a totally different piece of software.
2. It consistently refuses to replace curly apostrophes with the correct version and will often leave two open or closed curly apostrophes in the same quote. It does not appear to do this in the main body of the document, only the footnotes.
3. It will sometimes refuse to allow me to delete certain characters in the references acting as if they are not there and leaping over them when I push backspace. I have to delete a chunk of the reference and type it back in to get the pesky character.
4. Word is refusing to update any of the references with the proper numbers in the body text, and will only refresh the numbering in the footnotes themselves thereby throwing all of my footnotes out of synch if I decide to delete one.
5. I change the footnotes using the paragraph style I have created. However, on some of them when I go back it refuses to show the text style being used in the Ribbon and the Font shows up with no name.

I have used Google font Lora for the body and Noto Sans for the footnotes. Does anyone have any idea what is breaking the software? I have had other very patchy and unpredictable issues, but I am forced to work in Word due to the proofreaders and typsetters being unable to work with anything but MS WORD.

Comment: You might try a test using free LibreOffice Writer on that Mac -- Writer can load and save in *many* formats, including MS Word DOCX and old DOC. See if it works better than MS Word importing the document.

Comment: I have tried LibreOffice and unfortunately it is far worse at importing and exporting. It routinely crashes on my system, so much so I had to unistall it.